# Corecursion vs Recursion understanding in scala

Tags: scala, function, recursion, functional-programming

if with recursion almost clear, for example

```
 def product2(ints: List[Int]): Int = {
      @tailrec
      def productAccumulator(ints: List[Int], accum: Int): Int = {
          ints match {
              case Nil => accum
              case x :: tail => productAccumulator(tail, accum * x)
          }
      }
      productAccumulator(ints, 1)
  }
```

I am not sure about to the corecursion. According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion), "*corecursion allows programs to produce arbitrarily complex and potentially infinite data structures, such as streams*". For example construction like this

```
list.filter(...).map(...)
```

makes to posible prepare temporary streams after `filter` and `map` operations. 
after `filter` stream will be collect only filtered elements, and next in the `map` we will change elements. Correct?

Do functional combinators use recursion executions for `map` `filter`
Does any body have good example in Scala "comparing recursion and corecursion"?

Comment: According to wiki definition, your example of `product` **is** corecursion. `product` as recursion would look like `def product(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match { case Nil => 1 case x :: xs => x * product(xs) }`

Comment: no - the example here is not corecursion - it's a special case of a fold implemented with recursion. - The stuff with corecursion is for example  `Iterable<..>` in Java-world

Comment: Do you mean foldLeft or foldRight is corecursion ?

Answer (score 14):

The simplest way to understand the difference is to think that recursion *consumes* data while corecursion *produces* data. Your example is recursion since it consumes the list you provide as parameter. Also, *foldLeft* and *foldRight* are recursion too, not corecursion. Now an example of corecursion. Consider the following function:

```
def unfold[A, S](z: S)(f: S => Option[(A, S)]): Stream[A]
```

Just by looking at its signature you can see this function is intended to *produce* an infinite stream of data. It takes an initial state, `z` of type `S`, and a function from `S` to a possible tuple that will contain the next state and the actual value of the stream, that is of type `A`. If the result of `f` is empty (`None`) then `unfold` stops producing elements otherwise it goes on passing the next state and so on. Here is its implementation:

```
def unfold[S, A](z: S)(f: S => Option[(A, S)]): Stream[A] = f(z) match {
  case Some((a, s)) => a #:: unfold(s)(f)
  case None => Stream.empty[A]
}
```

You can use this function to implement other *productive* functions. E.g. the following function will produce a stream of, at most, `numOfValues` elements of type `A`:

```
def elements[A](element: A, numOfValues: Int): Stream[A] = unfold(numOfValues) { x =>
  if (x > 0) Some((element, x - 1)) else None
}
```

Usage example in REPL:

```
scala> elements("hello", 3)
res10: Stream[String] = Stream(hello, ?)

scala> res10.toList
res11: List[String] = List(hello, hello, hello)
```