# Corecursion understanding

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

according to the wikipedia Corecursion - works synthetically, starting from a base case and building it up, iteratively producing data further removed from a base case.

Do functional combinators make co-recursion ?
like

```
list.map(...).filter(..)
```

Any corecursion examples with scala?

BR!

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the question you asked yesterday

Comment: possible duplicate of [Corecursion vs Recursion understanding in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479852/corecursion-vs-recursion-understanding-in-scala)

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page lists factorials and the Fibonacci series as examples of corecursion, both of which can be implemented as an infinite `Stream()`.

```
// factorial
val facs: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: facs.zipWithIndex.map(x=>x._1 * (x._2+1))

// fibonacci
val fibs: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fibs.scan(1)(_+_)
```